# While con Python

Tags: python-3.x

Compañeros hola, tengo este codigo en python, lo que hace es ponerle a la primera letra de los elementos de una lista en mayuscula:

```
listString = ['sena','adsi','programacion','dios']
def listUpper(x):
    x= [element.capitalize() for element in x]
    print(x)
    return listUpper
print(listUpper(listString))
```

Aqui lo hice usando un ciclo for pero no he podido hacerlo con While

Comment: Lo que has usado en realidad tampoco es un ciclo for, sino lo que python llama una "comprensión de listas". Es una forma de ciclo encubierto. Por otro lado es código no puede funcionar porque lo que retornas en la función no es `x` (la lista una vez convertida), sino `listUpper` (que es la propia función). Estás retornando una función. Por tanto el `print()` del programa principal imprimirá algo como `<function listUpper at 0x100931e18>`, y sólo _aparentemente_ funciona porque también has impreso `x` desde dentro de la función (cosa que no deberías hacer si retornas `x`)

Comment: En cuanto a hacerlo con `while`, sería mucho más ineficiente, pero sospecho que se trata de un ejercicio académico en el que te lo piden hacerlo así. En ese caso te dejo que lo pienses cambiando el enfoque. Deberás usar un entero (por ejemplo `i`) para acceder a cada elemento de la lista. Comenzarás con `i=0` y repetirás  un bucle _mientras_ (`while`) ese entero sea menor que la longitud de la lista, y en cada iteración cambiarás `x[i]` por su versión en mayúsculas. No olvides incrementar `i` en cada iteración

Comment: Cual es la pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Si la pregunta es que quieres hacerlo con un while y no se te occurre como, la solución podria se similar a la que te di en la otra pregunta:

```
listString = ['sena','adsi','programacion','dios']

def listUpper(x):
    def _listUpper(x):
        c = 0
        while c < len(x):
            yield x[c].capitalize()
            c += 1
    return list(_listUpper(x))

print(listUpper(listString))
```

En palabras simples, puedes reemplazar cualquier:

```
for i in iterator:
    # do something
```

por su versión en `while`

```
c = 0
while c < len(iterador):
   # do something
   c += 1
```

un contador y while contador < len(iterador)

Comment: Aunque tu solución es perfectamente válida, creo que es demasiado avanzada para el nivel de quien ha hecho la pregunta. Si no tiene claro cómo resolver un bucle while es obviamente alguien que está empezando. Darle una solución que implica funciones dentro de funciones y generadores puede confundirle. La segunda parte de la respuesta la veo mejor y te doy +1.